# Why did Clara want to be like the Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

In series 8 and 9 Clara tries to be like the Doctor:

> DOCTOR: Now, listen! You're going to need these.
>
> CLARA: Oh, wow. This is an honour. Does this mean I'm you now?
>
> DOCTOR: No, it does not, so don't get any ideas.
>
> <sub>-- *Flatline* (Series 8)</sub>

then she is the Doctor for a day using psychic paper and sonic screwdriver:

> CLARA: I'm the Doctor.
>
> DOCTOR: Don't you dare.
>
> CLARA [OC]: Doctor Oswald.
>
> CLARA: But you can call me Clara.
>
> RIGSY: I'm Rigsy. So er, what are you a doctor of?
>
> DOCTOR: Of lies.
>
> CLARA [OC]: Well, I'm usually quite vague about that.
>
> CLARA: I think I just picked the title because it makes me sound important.
>
> <sub>-- *Flatline* (Series 8)</sub>

then she asks if she did a good job:

> CLARA: Admit it. I did well.
>
> CLARA: Just say it. Why can't you just say it? Why can't you just say I did good?
>
> CLARA:  Come on, why can't you say it? I was the Doctor and I was good.
>
> DOCTOR: You were an exceptional Doctor, Clara.
>
> CLARA: Thank you.
>
> <sub>-- *Flatline* (Series 8)</sub>

Then in series 9 she starts being him:

> CLARA: This is Doctor 101. We're buying time. We get all of the aliens on our side in the next half an hour, and then we reveal I've got the chronolock, not you, and boom! We buy ourselves more time to find the real killer.
>
> CLARA: Doctor 102. Never tell anyone your actual plan. He'll have a tantrum when he finds out. And then, when we confront Ashildr, she'll want to take the chronolock off just to shut him up.
>
> <sub>-- *Face the Raven* (Series 9)</sub>

Then in *Hell Bent* the Doctor gives Clara advice on how to be a Doctor:

> DOCTOR: Run like hell, because you always need to. Laugh at everything, because it's always funny.
>
> CLARA: No. Stop it. You're saying goodbye. Don't say goodbye!
>
> DOCTOR: Never be cruel and never be cowardly. And if you ever are, always make amends.
>
> CLARA: Stop it! Stop this. Stop it!
>
> DOCTOR: Never eat pears. They're too squishy and they always make your chin wet. That one's quite important. Write it down
>
> <sub>-- *Hell Bent* (Series 9)</sub>

She takes that advice and takes a TARDIS with Me and goes to Gallifrey the long way around just like the Doctor.

**Why did Clara want to be like the Doctor?**

Comment: im asking why Clara wanted to be like the doctor

Comment: Have you ever been to a science fiction convention? A lot of people want to be the Doctor.

Comment: i have been but im asking why Clara shes not a timelord no 2 hearts or regeneration or sonic screwdriver and no physic paper

Comment: None of the people at science fiction conventions have 2 hearts or regenerations or sonic screwdrivers or psychic paper either. No human being does, but quite a few have done a fairly good job at "being the Doctor" from time to time (Jackson Lake and Clara both spring to mind immediately).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Why wouldn't she want to be like the Doctor? Everyone does!

The Doctor is an attractive figure, not always only in the physical sense.
When things seem most hopeless, he (in that particular incarnation, though the Doctor's gender varies) bursts onto the scene in his time machine, and, with a few words and a wave of his screwdriver, dismantles the villains' carefully built plans.

He has done a [lot of terrible things](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124976/why-doesnt-the-doctor-consider-himself-a-hero), but he has also achieved many incredible things. He is, though he does not recognize it, a hero. He has saved the entire human race hundreds of times, the universe several times, and the *entire Doctor Who multiverse* at least once.

He defeated the Master when he attempted to subjugate humanity with the Toclafane , and when he attempted to rule the universe by releasing the entropy wave from Logopolis, or when he tried to turn all humans on Earth into his clones, or when....

He stopped the Daleks in the xenocidal crusade again and again, even preventing them from destroying all universes at the Medusa Cascade.

He defeated the Cybermen, the Great Intelligence, the Memeovore, the Fendahl, the Silence, the Great Intelligence.

He has had to make some pretty difficult decisions, and sometimes made the wrong ones, but he always *cares*.

**To his companions, the Doctor must be the very embodiment of adventure.
They all grow to admire him in some respect.**

Indeed, Rose, Martha, Jack, and Amy (among others) fell in love with the Doctor.

And Clara travels with this person for years. Of course she will admire him. Of course she will want to be like him.

Even Moffat [wants to be the Doctor](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Doctor_Who):

> "But when they made this particular hero, they didn't give him a
> gun--they gave him a screwdriver to fix things. They didn't give him a
> tank or a warship or an x-wing fighter--they gave him a box from which
> you can call for help. And they didn't give him a superpower or pointy
> ears or a heat-ray--they gave him an extra HEART. They gave him two
> hearts! And that's an extraordinary thing.  There will never come a
> time when we don't need a hero like the Doctor.”

### Travelling with the Doctor is the focus of her life

Far more than any other companion on the new series (well, except Jack),  Clara has much less to tie her to Earth. Rose had her mother (and her alternate-universe father, and initially Mickey). Martha had her parents and siblings. Donna had her grandfather and her mother.  Rory and Amy had each other. Clara had Danny Pink, and then he died. **It is no coincidence that she threw herself into travelling with the Doctor after this loss.**

When travelling, and adventuring, and heroism became all of Clara's life, it was the first step on the path to becoming like the Doctor. After all, his lifestyle became the very model for hers.

All the other companions experienced this, to some degree. Witness Martha taking up alien fighting with UNIT, or Jack working with Torchwood, or Sarah Jane Smith running her own outfit for managing extraterrestrial threats (and allies).

**All of the Doctor's companions become more like the Doctor.** It was strongest for Clara, because she had so few other ties.

### **Clara doesn't want to grow an extra heart, or expose herself to the Time Vortex. She wants to be a hero. And the Doctor is her nearest role model.**

Comment: But she can't master what he did in his past incarnations

Comment: @AndrewCasali: So what? She doesn't need to. She has a hero and she wants to imitate him. I believe you're massively overthinking this.

Comment: No I'm not I was just curious